# insert-koin: How to inject MVP activity view interface into presenter?

Tags: android, koin

I am an Android Developer and I use MVP when designing my apps. I recently got word of Insert-Koin and I like it the more I use it. However, when converting my app to use Koin I need to pass my activity view interface to the presenter as a result wouldn't that mean I need to inject my activity also? I have looked at the MVP example and it is not very clear as they do not pass the activity view interface directly it instead is done through an RxPresenter object (no idea).

Would appreciate a clarification on how to inject an activities view interface to my presenter.

Here is a presenter from the example MVP code:
https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/tree/master/koin-projects/examples/android-mvp/src/main/kotlin/fr/ekito/myweatherapp/view/detail

```
class DetailPresenter(
    private val id: String,
    private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepository,
    private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) : RxPresenter<DetailContract.View>(), DetailContract.Presenter {

    override var view: DetailContract.View? = null

    override fun getDetail() {
        launch {
            weatherRepository.getWeatherDetail(id).with(schedulerProvider).subscribe(
                { detail ->
                    view?.showDetail(detail)
                }, { error -> view?.showError(error) })
        }
    }
}
```

then the activity:

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DetailContract.View {

    // Detail id passed by argument
    private val detailId by argument<String>(ARG_WEATHER_ITEM_ID)

    override val presenter: DetailContract.Presenter by inject { parametersOf(detailId) }
```

Where is 'view' actually assigned?!?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the linked example, you'll see that in DetailActivity.onStart() `presenter.subscribe(this)` is called (line 31).

It's a method of the interface BasePresenter, that DetailContract.Presenter implements (through RxPresenter); it's overridden in RxPresenter and it does indeed assign the View  to the Presenter.

Please note the essential call to `presenter.unSubscribe()` in DetailActivity.onStop() (line 36)  to not leak the activity instance!